# in_array() not working even when the value does exist

Tags: php, wordpress

Maybe it's too late and I am being dumb but `in_array()` is not working for me like it usually would:

```php
    if(is_user_logged_in()):
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $recommendedHost = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_highly_recommended' );
        var_dump($recommendedHost); //array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "48" [1]=> string(2) "14" } }

        var_dump($eventHostID); // int(14)

        if( in_array($eventHostID, $recommendedHost) ) {
            //$eventRecommended = true;
            echo 'yes';
        } else {
            echo 'no';
        }

        //Results: no

    endif;
```

I've also tried converting the `int` to a `str` but that changes nothing as expecting since by default `in_array()` doesn't match the data type for the `$needle`.

Comment: `$recommendedHost` is an array of arrays. The value you're looking for in is `$recommendedHost[0]`, not `$recommendedHost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly old me, `in_array()` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays. I had to run a `foreach` loop to go over all the arrays and then check each of those single dimension arrays for the needle.

```php
    if(is_user_logged_in()):
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $recommendedHosts = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_highly_recommended' );
        $eventRecommended = '';

        foreach($recommendedHosts as $recommendedHost){
            if( in_array($eventHostID, $recommendedHost) ) {
                $eventRecommended = true;
            }
        }
    endif;?>
```

Comment: Or, assuming that your array has just one array inside it (as the one you posted above), you could also do something like `in_array($eventHostID, $recommendedHost[0])`. Your answer works too of course.